# How to send variable value to pipe while hiding it from the process list?

Tags: shell-script, security, pipe, environment-variables

I'm writing a simple shell script that reads a PIN once (into a variable) and uses it to call several commands that needs this pin. It is possible to instruct those commands to read PIN from stdin, but I don't know how to send the variable value to a pipe without revealing it in a process list. Usual way - using `echo "$PIN"` - would perform a substitution so the value of PIN would be visible to other users via process list.

Is there a command that accepts a variable name and outputs that variable's value to stdout? Or is there some other way?

Comment: `echo` is usually a built-in utility and won't show up in the process list.

Comment: I haven't realized that, you are right. I will leave this question open for answers that would solve the minor case when echo is not built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As `echo` is builtin in all shells, it won't show in the process list.

[It is however unreliable for arbitrary data](/q/65803)

You can use `printf '%s\n' "$PIN"` for something more reliable, but note  that some pdksh-based shells still don't have `printf`  builtin. The work around for those is to use `print -r -- "$PIN"`. `print` is available in `zsh`, and all implementations of `ksh`, but is not a standard command.

You can also use a here-document:

```
cmd << EOF
$PIN
EOF
```

(or here-string (`cmd <<< "$PIN"`) in `zsh` and a few other shells now). But note that with most implementations, here-documents are implemented with temporary files, so the PIN may be recoverable offline if the file was committed to disk.

It's better not to export `PIN` to the environment if you can avoid it as it's more easily discoverable by other processes (seen in `/proc/pid/environ` which processes with the same uid can read, while there are  often more restrictions as to what can read the memory of another process). `ps` on some (rare) systems also let you see the environment of any process.

Once in the environment though, on some systems, there's a `printenv` command to display its value:

```
printenv PIN
```

Or you can always use `perl`:

```
perl -le 'print $ENV{PIN}'
```

Comment: I have corrected the quoting.